# I am having trouble in locating search bus button in red bus site using selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","./drivers/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("search_btn")).click();
}
```

Html code:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mdsv.png][https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODjxk.png]

I am not able to click the search bus button.

Comment: Your description is not clear, add html source code of the page, add error what are you faced with

Comment: You will need to include the HTML you are searching, or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: sorry for that.Newbee of stackoverflow.I didnt upload the img properly and now I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to locate the **Search Buses** button and invoke `click()` you can use either of the following line of code :

- **`cssSelector`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.fl.button#search_btn")).click();
  ```
- **`xpath`**

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='fl button' and @id='search_btn']")).click();
  ```

---

### Update

With *Selenium-Java Client v3.9.1* , *GeckoDriver v0.19.1* and *Firefox Quantum v58.0.2* this block of code works perfect at my end :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button.fl.button#search_btn"))).click();
System.out.println("Search button clicked");
driver.quit();
```

Console Output :

```
Search button clicked
```

Snapshot :

[image: Search button clicked]

Comment: I still not able to click search bus button using these @DebanjanB.

Comment: @ DebanjanB I followed exactly as u mentioned and I tried using the same(With Selenium-Java Client v3.9.1 , GeckoDriver v0.19.1 and Firefox Quantum v58.0.2 ) it runs fine in console but in browser it is opening the redbus link but it is still not clicking the search button.Did the search click wrk for u?

Comment: See the `System.out.println("Search button clicked");` command and the output in the snapshot.

Comment: Try the updated code with `WebDriverwait` and let me know the status.

Comment: @ DebanjanB Tq..The button is clicking bt the problem is with alert box when the button is clicked so only it is not traversing to corresponding page.

Comment: @priyankamurugesan If you fill up the `From`, `To` and `Onward` fields, this code will definitely `click()` on the search button and fetch you search results.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='search']
//button[@id='search_btn']")).click();
```